# Find 'most clicked' variant in an array of objects, given a nested array of variants in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested, circular-reference

I have an array of objects called `articles`. An article has 3 important properties. `name`, `clicks`, and `variants`. The `variants` property is also an array of objects that contain `name` (It corresponds to an article in the array `articles`). What is the *most efficient way* to find each article's most clicked variant?

I thought maybe there was some way to use a map or spread operator, but I don't understand the syntax. I think I could create a 'dictionary' with the most clicked article for each set, but is there an easier way?

Input:

```
[
 {name: "article1",
 clicks: 10,
 variants: ["article2", "article3"]},

 {name: "article2",
 clicks: 7,
 variants: ["article1", "article3"]},

 {name: "article3",
 clicks: 15,
 variants: ["article1", "article2"]},

 {name: "article4",
 clicks: 3,
 variants: ["article5"]},

 {name: "article5",
 clicks: 6,
 variants: ["article4"]},
]
```

Desired output:

```
{name: "article1",
clicks: 10,
variants: ["article2", "article3"],
mostClickedVariant: "article3"}

{name: "article2",
clicks: 7,
variants: ["article1", "article3"],
mostClickedVariant: "article3"},
```

etc. for each article

Comment: you need quotes around strings.

Comment: You need a recursive procedure to total the clicks. But you need to prevent loops, so the recursion needs to remember all the nodes that it has traversed and check the current node against this to prevent hitting it again.

Comment: You don't need recursion if all variants are contained in every object @Barmar.

Comment: you can do reduce to find max object and then do map

Comment: @KaitlynForks I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This version does not mutate the original, just returns a copy with the new properties added.  It also uses a more efficient way to find maxima, reducing the list to its maximum in `O (n)` time, rather than using an `O (n log n)` `sort`.

```js
const maxBy = (fn) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  ({m, mx}, x, _, __, v = fn (x)) => v > m ? {m: v, mx: x} : {m, mx}, 
  {m: -Infinity}
) .mx

const addMostClicked = (
  articles, 
  index = new Map (articles .map (({name, clicks}) => [name, clicks])),
  findMax = maxBy((x) => index .get (x))
) => articles .map (
  (article) => ({... article, mostClickedVariant: findMax (article .variants)})
)

const articles = [{name: "article1", clicks: 10, variants: ["article2", "article3"]}, {name: "article2", clicks: 7, variants: ["article1", "article3"]}, {name: "article3", clicks: 15, variants: ["article1", "article2"]}, {name: "article4", clicks: 3, variants: ["article5"]}, {name: "article5", clicks: 6, variants: ["article4"]}]

console .log (addMostClicked (articles))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We first create an index mapping the article names to their click counts, and, using the helper `maxBy`, we create a function, `findMax` that will find the name associated with the largest click count.

Then we simply map over the elements, returning copies with new `mostClickedVariant` properties determined by calling `findMax` with the list of variant names.

Answer (score 0):

According to your expectations:

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import { Classifier } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/Classifier.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [
        {name: "article1",
        clicks: 10,
        variants: ["article2", "article3"]},
       
        {name: "article2",
        clicks: 7,
        variants: ["article1", "article3"]},
       
        {name: "article3",
        clicks: 15,
        variants: ["article1", "article2"]},
       
        {name: "article4",
        clicks: 3,
        variants: ["article5"]},
       
        {name: "article5",
        clicks: 6,
        variants: ["article4"]},
    ],

    expected =  [
        {name: "article1",
        clicks: 10,
        variants: ["article2", "article3"],
        mostClickedVariant: "article3"},
       
        {name: "article2",
        clicks: 7,
        variants: ["article1", "article3"],
        mostClickedVariant: "article3"},
       
        {name: "article3",
        clicks: 15,
        variants: ["article1", "article2"],
        mostClickedVariant: "article1"},
       
        {name: "article4",
        clicks: 3,
        variants: ["article5"],
        mostClickedVariant: "article5"},
       
        {name: "article5",
        clicks: 6,
        variants: ["article4"],
        mostClickedVariant: "article4"},
       ]
```

However, since the `mostClickedVariant` can be derived from your data, it's advisable to define it using a function rather than as a property. This approach prevents redundancy in your data.
A function `sortedVariants(article)` can provide the flexibility to return all variants, sorted by clicks.

It's worthwhile to consider why you're interested in sorting the variants of each article but seemingly not interested in sorting the entire collection of articles.

Moreover, I propose distinguishing between two types of information in your dataset: the `clicks` per article and the `relationships` among articles. It's beneficial to recognize and separate these different types of information.

```
const
    clicks = new Classifier()
        .letAll(data.map(obj => [obj.clicks, obj.name])),

    relationships = new Classifier()
        .letAll(data.map(obj => obj.variants
                .map(variant => [obj.name, variant]))
            .flat()),

    sortedVariants = name => new TrueSet(variant => clicks.class(undefined, variant).what()[0])
        .letAll(relationships.class(name).then(entry => entry[1]))
```

The articles are sorted by clicks whereas the relations among articles are sorted alphabetically. The method `sortedVariants(name)` returns a `TrueSet` representing, in ascending order, each variant with the number of clicks:

`variant => clicks.class(undefined, variant).what()[0]`.

The method `what()` returns the first and sole entry `[clicks, article]` of the class. The most clicked variant is, therefore, last variant in the set, which can be retrived by `peek(false)`.

You can validate the proposed solution by:

```
assert.deepEqual(
    data.map(obj => sortedVariants(obj.name).peek(false)), 
    expected.map(obj => obj.mostClickedVariant)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (I added all the descriptive comments in the below code snippet) **:**

```js
// Input array
const arr = [
  {name: "article1",
   clicks: 10,
   variants: ["article2", "article3"]},

  {name: "article2",
   clicks: 7,
   variants: ["article1", "article3"]},

  {name: "article3",
   clicks: 15,
   variants: ["article1", "article2"]},

  {name: "article4",
   clicks: 3,
   variants: ["article5"]},

  {name: "article5",
   clicks: 6,
   variants: ["article4"]},
];

// Iterating over an input array.
const res = arr.map(obj => {
  // Fetching variant objects in an array based on the variants name we have in the array. 
  const variantArr = obj.variants.map(variant => arr.find(o => o.name === variant));
  // Getting most clicked variant object by sorting the variantArr in desc order based on the clicks.
  const mostClickedVariant = variantArr.sort((a, b) => b.clicks - a.clicks)[0];
  // creating a new property 'mostClickedVariant' in each obejct and assigning the name of the most clicked variant.
  obj.mostClickedVariant = mostClickedVariant.name;
  return obj;
});

// Expected output
console.log(res);
```